# using limit in a mysql subquery. easiest alternative?

Tags: mysql

I have these sample records:

```
Master Image Table (named Image)

ImgID    aFile     AlbumID
1        abc.jpg   1
2        def.jpg   1
3        ghi.jpg   1
1        Qyz.jpg   2
2        Qxz.jpg   2
3        Qxq.jpg   2
1        Xyz.jpg   3
2        Xxz.jpg   3
3        Xxq.jpg   3


Album table

AlbumID    Date
1          2013-01-02
2          2014-01-03
3          2012-01-03
```

Each week, a new album of images is added to the database and the date is stamped. What I want to retrieve at all times is the first two image filenames from only the latest album. In this case, the values should be Qyz.jpg and Qxz.jpg

This is what I have tried so far in SQL:

```
select aFile from Image,Album where Image.AlbumID=Album.AlbumID and AlbumID in (select AlbumID from Album order by Date Desc limit 0,1) order by ImgID asc limit 0,2
```

Mysql returns this error:

```
This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' []
```

and I believe I'm using mysql version 5.0. Is there a solution to this without me upgrading mysql and without me making two separate queries?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way. It doesn't scale particularly well ,so if it seems slow then take a look at a solution using variables.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS images;

CREATE TABLE images
(image_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
,filename VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE
,album_id INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(album_id,image_id)
)ENGINE = MyISAM;

INSERT INTO images VALUES
(1,'abc.jpg',1),
(2,'def.jpg',1),
(3,'ghi.jpg',1),
(1,'Qyz.jpg',2),
(2,'Qxz.jpg',2),
(3,'Qxq.jpg',2),
(1,'Xyz.jpg',3),
(2,'Xxz.jpg',3),
(3,'Xxq.jpg',3);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS albums;

CREATE TABLE albums
(album_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY 
,date DATE NOT NULL 
);

INSERT INTO albums VALUES
(1,'2013-01-02'),
(2,'2014-01-03'),
(3,'2012-01-03');

SELECT a.*,c.*
  FROM albums a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MAX(date) max_date FROM albums) b 
    ON b.max_date = a.date 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.* 
         FROM images x
         JOIN images y 
           ON y.album_id = x.album_id 
          AND y.image_id <= x.image_id 
        GROUP 
           BY x.album_id
            , x.image_id 
       HAVING COUNT(*) <=2
     ) c 
    ON c.album_id = a.album_id;

+----------+------------+----------+----------+----------+
| album_id | date       | image_id | filename | album_id |
+----------+------------+----------+----------+----------+
|        2 | 2014-01-03 |        1 | Qyz.jpg  |        2 |
|        2 | 2014-01-03 |        2 | Qxz.jpg  |        2 |
+----------+------------+----------+----------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind both images being in a single string, then here's a really hacky way with `GROUP_CONCAT` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX` (since `GROUP_CONCAT` doesn't have a `LIMIT`).

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(aFile ORDER BY ImgID ASC), ',', 2) AS files
FROM Image
JOIN Album USING(AlbumID)
GROUP BY AlbumID
ORDER BY Date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This should return a single row like so:

```
files
Qyz.jpg,Qxz.jpg
```